# Big right brace in enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate, cases, braces, aligned

I'm trying to do a `cases` environment with a brace on the right using the classic trick `\left. \begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned} \right\}` but the particularity is that I'm in an enumerate environment and this gives me the following results depending on where I put the `[t]` in the `aligned` environment.

[image]

Here is the code that produced this:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    $\begin{aligned}
        \left.
        \begin{aligned}[t]
            &y=\frac{d}{x} \, \Rightarrow \, y^2=\frac{d^2}{x^2} \\[1ex]
            &y^2=db-dx
        \end{aligned} \right\}
    \end{aligned}$
    \item
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
        \left.
        \begin{aligned}
            &y=\frac{d}{x} \, \Rightarrow \, y^2=\frac{d^2}{x^2} \\[1ex]
            &y^2=db-dx
        \end{aligned} \right\}
    \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Also, the `rcases` environment gives me the same result as 2.

The problem is that I don't want either. I want kind of a mix of the two where the first equation is aligned with the 1. or 2. and the brace is not way too big.

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can measure the height of the top `aligned` (without the brace) and the height of the `aligned` with the brace. Then lower the latter so the reference point agrees with the former.

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{itemaligned}{b}{%
  \sbox0{$\begin{aligned}[t]#1\end{aligned}$}%
  \sbox2{$\left.\begin{aligned}#1\end{aligned}\right\}$}%
  \raisebox{\dimeval{\ht0-\ht2}}{\usebox{2}}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{itemaligned}
      &y=\frac{d}{x} \, \Rightarrow \, y^2=\frac{d^2}{x^2} \\[1ex]
      &y^2=db-dx
    \end{itemaligned}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add a formula centered with respect to the brace with a slight modification: such a formula should go as optional argument to `itemaligned` as shown in the code below.

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{itemaligned}{ob}{%
  \sbox0{$\begin{aligned}[t]#2\end{aligned}$}%
  \sbox2{%
    $\left.\begin{aligned}#2\end{aligned}\right\}%
    \IfValueT{#1}{\displaystyle{}#1}$%
  }%
  \raisebox{\dimeval{\ht0-\ht2}}{\usebox{2}}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \begin{itemaligned}[\Rightarrow \frac{d^2}{x^2}=db-dx]
      &y=\frac{d}{x} \, \Rightarrow \, y^2=\frac{d^2}{x^2} \\[1ex]
      &y^2=db-dx
    \end{itemaligned}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! But I still have a problem: I would like to write an equation to the right of the brace that is centered but when I try to do so, it keeps aligning it to the top. How do I center it ?

Comment: @IsaKEKW I can only answer what's asked. Anyway, see the edit. Now what I'd like to see in a paper or a printed book.

Answer (score 4):

With `tikzmark` library of `tikz` package. For nice braces are employed `decorations.pathreplacing` and `calligraphy` too:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,%
                calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                tikzmark}
\tikzset{BC/.style  = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
                        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
                        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
            raise = 6pt,
                    #1},% for mirroring of brace, if needed
            ultra thick,
            pen colour={black}},
        }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
          y & = \dfrac{d}{x} \, \Rightarrow \, y^2 = \tikzmarknode{A}{\dfrac{d^2}{x^2}} \\
        y^2 & = db - \tikzmarknode{B}{dx}          \\
        \end{aligned}$
    \item
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
          y & = \dfrac{d}{x} \, \Rightarrow \, y^2 = \tikzmarknode{C}{\dfrac{d^2}{x^2}} \\
        y^2 & = db-dx         &   \\
          E & = M\cdot\tikzmarknode{D}{C^2}    &   \\
        \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw[BC]   (A.north east) -- (A.east |- B.south);
\draw[BC]   (C.north east) -- (C.east |- D.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

After at least two compilation the result of above MWE is:

[image]

With this solution you can change color of braces. For example that them be red by set `pen colour={red}`.

**Addendum:**
In cases, when you like that to curly braces follows some equation, than just add node with this equation to curly braces:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,%
                calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                tikzmark}
\tikzset{BC/.style  = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
                        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
                        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
            raise = 6pt,
                    #1},% for mirroring of brace, if needed
            ultra thick,
            pen colour={black}},
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
          y & = \dfrac{d}{x} \, \Rightarrow \, y^2 = \tikzmarknode{A}{\dfrac{d^2}{x^2}} \\
        y^2 & = db - \tikzmarknode{B}{dx}          \\
        \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw[BC]   (A.north east) -- node[right=5mm] {$\dfrac{d^2}{x^2}=db-dx$} (A.east |- B.south);  % <---
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The TikZ brackets aren't quite big enough. The top and bottom need to be above/below the top and bottom of the text it brackets. You can see this in the answer of @egreg.

Comment: @Simd, this is mater of taste. I make a braces shorter by purpose. If you not like this, remove code lines `pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt, 
                  post=moveto, post length=1pt,` in style definition for `BC`.

Answer (score 3):

Come out this idea as a workaround. Depends on your real useage, this method may not be working. There must be a better solution.

Using `tabular` env to type the equations in different rows and using `multirow` and `resizebox` to type the right bracket with suitable size.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}l}
        $\displaystyle y=\frac{d}{x} \, \Rightarrow \, y^2=\frac{d^2}{x^2}$&\multirow{2}{*}{\resizebox{11pt}{28pt}{\}}}\\
        $y^2=db-dx$\\
        \end{tabular}
    \item         
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}l}
        $\displaystyle y=\frac{d}{x} \, \Rightarrow \, y^2=\frac{d^2}{x^2}$&\multirow{3}{*}{\resizebox{11pt}{48pt}{\}}}\\
        $y^2=db-dx$\\
        $E=M\cdot C^2$\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Those brackets are not the right size, sadly.